# How to convert a.b.c.d IP records to an IP value using a function in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, string

Here's the table I have...

```
user (
  id        int unsigned  primary key
  ip        varchar(15)   not null
  ip_value  int unsigned  default null
)
```

Some sample data

```
id    ip            ip_value
123   5.68.23.10    NULL
592   31.52.11.49   NULL
```

I need to update all records in the user table using a function.

If an IP is made up of parts A.B.C.D, `ip_value` can be calculated as such:

```
(A * 256 * 256 * 256) + (B * 256 * 256) + (C * 256) + D
```

Afterward, the table should look like this

```
id    ip            ip_value
123   5.68.23.10    88348426
592   31.52.11.49   523504433
```

How can I accomplish this using a MySQL query?

Comment: Sounds like you're halfway there already... just use string manipulation functions for the rest?

Comment: @cdhowie, that's the trouble, i don't know how to use the string functions to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the INET_ATON function to do it

```
SELECT id, ip, INET_ATON(ip) AS ip_value from your_table;
```

More info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton